# Missing First Letter of Short Description in Magento

Tags: php, magento, backend

I can add the short description to the back end with no worries, but when I look at the front end it is missing the first letter.

An example of this: http://www.bluescribecloud.com/index.php/nautical/bells/bronze-ship-s-bell-4.html

As you can see when you click on the page, to the right of the image is The Short Description text and the first letter is missing. This is the same for every product.

You can see the correct description in the description part at the bottom of the products name.

On a side note, is it possible to have it so that the short description ends with 3 trailing ellipses rather than ending abruptly?

Thanks!!!

Comment: can you please show where $_product->getShortDescription() is being echo'd in your view.phtml template

Comment: This is what that particular snippet of code looks like as requested: 

    `<?php if ($_product->getShortDescription()):?>
                    <div class="short-description">
                        <!--<h2><?php echo $this->__('Quick Overview') ?></h2>-->
      <?php $des = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description');?>
                        <div class="std"><?php echo  substr($des,1,200);?></div>
                    </div>
                <?php endif;?>   `

Comment: see the problem, ive added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bingo, change the code to this;

```
<?php if ($_product->getShortDescription()):?> 
<div class="short-description"> <!--<h2><?php echo $this->__('Quick Overview') ?></h2>--> 
<?php $des = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description');?> 
<div class="std">
<?php if(strlen($des) > 200) { 
echo substr($des,0,200).'...'; 
} else { 
echo $des; } ?>
</div></div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There certainly seems to be some issue when you echo'ed the description in you template file. Find the template used, and fix the issue, or you can mention the code here.